# why is btmp not showing the username of logged in users?

Tags: linux, command-line, login, who, btmp

I am trying to compare the output of the `btmp` file and `who -a` commands.

I don't know why, but `btmp file` currently is not showing the username but its showing `UNKNOWN` in the username field. I am (username:debian) logged in that session.

Please observe the output below:

```
virt00# who -a
           system boot  2016-03-06 19:36
           run-level 5  2016-03-06 19:36
debian   - tty1         2016-03-06 19:36 00:33        1006
debian   + pts/0        2016-03-06 19:43   .          1037 (192.168.56.1)

virt00# last -f /var/log/btmp | grep still
UNKNOWN  tty1                          Sat Feb 20 16:24   still logged in
virt00#
```

Could you please explain why is there adifference between these two and why I have logged in via SSH and there is one more session running at VM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/var/log/btmp` keeps track of *failed* login attempts.  If everyone is logged in without problems, there is nothing to show.

In testing the feature, I am only able to see "UNKNOWN" logged (on Debian 7) using telnet (not ssh) and if I give an unknown username at the prompt, causing a failure.  That is similar to the scenario shown in an Ubuntu thread [sshd doesn't add to /var/log/btmp](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1715684.html).  Connecting with ssh never generates a failure on this machine.

A quick read of the [source code](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/viewvc.php/sysvinit/trunk/src/?root=pkg-sysvinit) does not show anyplace that `last` would supply the `UNKNOWN` by itself.  That is probably from the application that created the record in `/var/log/btmp`.

In your configuration, it would seem that the login process was not able to get the actual user name and logged *that* as a problem in `/var/log/btmp`.  Like `utmp`, it is possible to have *stale* entries in `btmp` which are not deleted (the program which creates the entries is supposed to remove them — this is **not** done automatically).  Your example shows an entry a month old (February 20), and (since you are logged in as a known user on the same tty) is not related to your current login — and is from *before* the time the machine was most recently booted (March 3).

Further reading:

- [View utmp, wtmp and btmp files](http://www.linuxnix.com/read-view-utmp-wtmp-btmp-file-linuxunix/)
- [How to Read /var/log/btmp, Rotate the btmp Log With Logrotate](http://www.studiosacchetti.com/2011/how-to-read-varlogbtmp-rotate-the-btmp-log-with-logrotate/)
- [Difference between /var/log/btmp and /var/log/secure](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/difference-between-var-log-btmp-and-var-log-secure-4175534573/)

Comment: I understand but Mr Thomas If I am successfully login then why I have entry there ?

Comment: The file format is the same as `utmp` and `wtmp` which do have values for those fields. The time it happened as meaning in the context of `btmp` but it's not an event that spans a time range and so that field is probably left blank which is interpreted by `last` as meaning they're still logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `who -a` never reads `/var/log/btmp`, `who` reads `/var/run/utmp` and shows currently logged in user(s).

On the other hand, `/var/log/btmp` stores the failed login attempts.

---

I have reproduced the situation, i did:

- Went to `tty5` (could be any `tty`)
- Entered a user that do not exist on the system
- Given a random password
- The login prompt is back showing wrong password
- But there is an entry in `/var/log/btmp` as

  ```
  UNKNOWN  tty5  Mon Mar 21 16:16   still logged in
  ```

  After a while this has become:

  ```
  UNKNOWN  tty5  Mon Mar 21 16:16    gone - no logout
  ```

Comment: same point again ... then why btmp holds current loggin details ?

Comment: @Raja Reproduced..check